# Time series analysis ACF-PACF

Tags: time-series

I have run a ITS analysis on my dataset but I am unable to know which ARMA process to use. Please help understand how to select the ARMA process. I'm stuck.

[image]

Comment: post your dataset

Comment: I think you will find the information you need in the linked thread. Please 
read it. If it isn't what you want / you still have a question afterwards, 
come back here & edit your question to state what you learned & what you still 
need to know. Then we can provide the information you need without just 
duplicating material elsewhere that already didn't help you.

Comment: I want to run a gls regression model and i wanted to know from the ACF-PACF plots above, which lag should I used for autocorrelation modeling?

Comment: gung - not every aspect of ARIMA model is covered in that post.  What about level shifts?  what about variance change? what about seasonal pulses?  what about changes in trends?